# Node.js REST API deployed to Heroku, package.json "files" are not getting deployed

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have created a Node.js REST API. It uses SQL Server as the DB. I have successfully deployed version 1.0 of my app to HEROKU and its working just fine. 
I just deployed version 1.1 which uses .SQL files to load the queries used in the app. I did some reading and found that using the section below in my package.json will get these files included.

```
  "files": [
    "src/sqlServer/providers",
    "src/sqlServer/providerTypes",
    "src/sqlServer/services"
  ],
```

Locally when I run "NPM PACK" and I inspect the tgz file, all my .SQL files are present. I updated my HEROKU based GIT repo and did a build and it works without any errors. When I run my node.js API I get the below error in the logs.

> node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file
>   or directory, scandir '/app/src/sqlServer/providerTypes'

I am very new to HEROKU and a beginner with Node.js too. I looked through a lot of other SO posts but was unable to find an answer for my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `heroku rum bash` command found the issue. In my code I was looking for folder named "sqlServer" and the folder on the server was named  "SQLServer". I fixed this and app is now working!